# How can I sum up the row of numbers in C?

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

So I got an assignment to make a program. The program to create is using a variable starting from number 1. The value of this variable increases by 1 each iteration. Make a sum of the iteration values ​​before and then. Show the sum results in the terminal. If the sum is more than one hundred, the program will exit the iteration by issuing the words "the program is complete"

I'm not understanding this assignment, but I managed to make this code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
    int i,j,rows;
    printf("Enter number of rows: ");
    scanf("%d", &rows);
    for (i=1; i<=rows; ++i) {
        for (j=1; j<=i; ++j)

        { printf("%d ",j); }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The problem I get :

1. I need to know the number of rows that if I sum them up will be 100
2. I need to show the previous equation in the output, something like this:

   ```
   1 = 1
   1 + 2 = 3
   1 + 2 + 3 = 6
   1 + 2 + ... + etc = no more than 100
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a rough draft of some code to do what you want.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

int i,j,rows,sum;

printf("Enter number of rows: ");
scanf("%d", &rows);

for (i=1; i<=rows; i++) 
{
    sum = 0;

    for (j=1; j<=i; j++)
    { 
        sum += j;
        printf("%d ",j); 
    }


    printf(" : Sum = %i\n",sum);
    if(sum > 100)
    {
        printf("Program Complete\n");
        break;
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

[image: Sample Output]

Comment: You can easily grab the row that you want with this solution by just checking the value of the variable i when the program concludes.

Comment: how do you know in the first time,the number of row 20 when sum up will be 105?

Comment: when concluding from `i` ,i dont know what `i` value will be ?

Comment: The program will always have i = 14 be the one that sumsto over 100.

Comment: @LuckyPradana Do you need any more help on this? Or does this resolve your question?